# Binding to MS Access Local Database

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, shieldui

I am using the Shield UI ASP.NET chart and am trying to add an ms access data source for a pie chart.. I have created a database and a table and added it to the solution. The table contains some data, so that couldn’t be the problem. 
After this I configured the data source and specified the following select statement:

```
SELECT * FROM [Sales]
```

but the chart  showed no data.
I than changed the query to

```
SELECT [ID], [ProductName], [SaleAmount] FROM [Sales]
```

because probably there was a column name missing but there was no success either. In both cases I ran the query and it returned rows.
 What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you defined the axis for the chart? I don't know anything about the chart, but you'll need to define axis and groups so that the data can be interpreted.

Comment: Could u show code - how the chart is defined and bound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no data visualized on your chart while your database contains rows, the problem could be that you are not specifying the exact column needed for the chart. At design time when specifying the datasource the chart doesn’t acuire any specific field for any specific column. This means that you need to place some extra code:

```
<DataSeries>
    <shield:ChartBarSeries DataFieldY="SaleAmount">
    </shield:ChartBarSeries>
</DataSeries>
```

Furthermore- if you need to specify more than one series e.g. visualize more than one field you need to repeat that for each field adding the appropriate data series.
You may find more information here:

https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/asp.net.chart/databinding/data.source.controls